# php filter array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How do i filter the blow array and retrieve any value of key that i want to make use of. The sample code i use returned only `99`.

```
<?php
  $theArray = array(
            'DP' => 1, 'TA' => 2, 'TA' => 3, 'IC' => 4, 'TA' => 5,
            'JP' => 6, 'TA' => 7, 'DP' => 8, 'IR' => 9, 'TA' => 10,
            'TA' => 11, 'IR' => 12, 'TA' => 13, 'DP' => 14, 'TA' => 15,
            'TA' => 16, 'IR' => 17, 'TA' => 18, 'IC' => 19, 'TA' => 20,
            'TA' => 21, 'IC' => 22, 'TA' => 23, 'TA' => 24, 'TA' => 25,
            'JP' => 26, 'TA' => 27, 'TA' => 28, 'TA' => 29, 'TA' => 30,
            'TA' => 31, 'TA' => 32, 'TA' => 33, 'TA' => 34, 'DP' => 35,
            'TA' => 36, 'TA' => 37, 'DP' => 38, 'JP' => 39, 'TA' => 40,
            'TA' => 41, 'IC' => 42, 'TA' => 43, 'TA' => 44, 'IR' => 45,
            'IR' => 46, 'TA' => 47, 'TA' => 48, 'TA' => 49, 'TA' => 50,
            'TA' => 51, 'TA' => 52, 'JP' => 53, 'TA' => 54, 'TA' => 55,
            'TA' => 56, 'TA' => 57, 'TA' => 58, 'DP' => 59, 'TA' => 60,
            'IC' => 61, 'TA' => 62, 'TA' => 63, 'TA' => 64, 'TA' => 65,
            'TA' => 66, 'IR' => 67, 'IR' => 68, 'TA' => 69, 'DP' => 70,
            'DP' => 71, 'TA' => 72, 'TA' => 73, 'TA' => 74, 'TA' => 75,
            'TA' => 76, 'TA' => 77, 'TA' => 78, 'TA' => 79, 'IC' => 80,
            'TA' => 81, 'IC' => 82, 'TA' => 83, 'TA' => 84, 'TA' => 85,
            'TA' => 86, 'TA' => 87, 'IC' => 88, 'IR' => 89, 'TA' => 90,
            'TA' => 91, 'TA' => 92, 'JP' => 93, 'TA' => 94, 'TA' => 95,
            'TA' => 96, 'TA' => 97, 'TA' => 98, 'TA' => 99 
        );
        foreach($theArray as $key => $val){
            if($val == 'TA'){
                echo $key.',';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your array has multiple identical keys. It shouldn't.

Comment: @raina77ow Please how do i assign multiple value in 1 key?

Comment: By using an array as a value. For example: `'TA' => [73, 98, 99]` etc.

Comment: Your array will get over-write due to same indexes-https://eval.in/942165 . You need to use multidimensional array

Comment: If your entire array would be the other way round. I.e. `array(1 => 'DP', 2 =>  'TA' , 3 => 'TA', `... your foreach would work, and you would not have an issue with duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks guys i get the error, is not possible because of the multiple key i specified

Comment: @PhilipJems  i will recomend you to delete your question as it is not serving any useful purpose to anybody. You are losing your reputation as well (due to down-vote and i am afraid that it will happen more in upcoming days)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the keys of certain value from an array, use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), such as

```
print_r(array_keys($theArray, 'TA'));
```

> If the optional search_value is specified, then only the keys for that
>   value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are
>   returned.

Comment: did you checked OP's array as well as comment. Please check this and you will know what i am talking about- https://eval.in/942165

Comment: Thanks! Noticed that. OP could not get `99` from his array and sample code, `99` has never been a key in his array.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have the fix now, i was lazy to rearrange the array so i tried if i can filter it using any method.

```
<?php
    $theArray = array(
                'IC' => array(4,19,22,42,61,80,82,88),
                'IR' => array(9,12,17,45,46,67,68,89),
                'JP' => array(6,26,39,53,93),
                'DP' => array(1,8,14,35,38,59,70,71),
                'TA' => array(0,2,3,5,7,10,11,13,15,16,18,20,21,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,36,37,40,41,43,44,47,48,49,50,51,52,54,55,56,57,58,60,62,63,64,64,66,69,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,81,83,84,85,86,87,90,91,92,94,95,96,97,98,99)
    );
    foreach($theArray as $key => $val){
    if($key == 'TA'){
        foreach($val as $thisk){
            echo $thisk.',';
        }
      }
   }
?>
```

Thanks Guys

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$newArray = array_filter($theArray, function($value){
    return $value == "TA";
});
```

Comment: did you checked OP's array as well as comment. Please check this and you will know what i am talking about- https://eval.in/942165

Comment: `TA` is a key, not a value.